# Отваливается sshfs

Tags: linux, sshfs

Имеется 2 сервера в качестве серверов приложений и один файловый сервер. К файловому серверу подключаются 2 сервера приложений для доступа к файлам.

На одном из серверов отваливается подключение примерно раз в сутки в логе syslog такая ошибка

> kernel: [5499115.202786] sshfs[15014]: segfault at 7f36780018 ip 00007f370509d323 sp 00007f366$

Папка к которой подключен удаленный диск выглядит как битая мякгая ссылка то есть красным цветом в mc

При попытке подключится к ней еще раз пишет

> Transport endpoint is not connected

Все это дело решается umount и повторный коннект, но хотелось бы чтобы не отваливалось.

Самое интересное что на втором сервере точно такая же схема подключения, версия sshfs идентичная первому серверу, но там все стабильно.

Версия sshfs на обоих серверах

> SSHFS version 2.5
>   FUSE library version: 2.9.3
>   fusermount version: 2.9.3
>   using FUSE kernel interface version 7.19

Вопрос какие варианты решения данной проблемы?

Comment: *решается umount* — вроде бы, примонтированное с помощью fuse, надо отмонтировать программой fusermount. это просто к слову.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, только если точка была изначально была монтирована в контексте обычного пользователя, а не от root'а. В остальных случаях особой разницы нет.

Comment: Память битая возможно на сервере и сегфолтится ссх, ещё можно попробовать обновить пакет sshfs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Происходит [segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)  - в sshfs присутствует некая ошибка, из-за которой в некий момент он пытается прочитать/записать что-то в область памяти, которая ему не доступна.

Если у вас достаточно мотивации - соберите на том сервере sshfs с отладочной информацией, запустите под `gdb`(либо с libSegFault + addr2line), да получите `backtrace` в момент возникновения ошибки.
После этого можете либо просто отправить эту информацию в [Issues](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues)(в текущей версии, без backtrace'а её слишком мало для работы над исправлением), либо самостоятельно исправить ошибку в коде и отправить [Pull Request](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/pulls).

Правда sshfs фактически заброшен с 2011-го года(ну не считая обновлений всяких ReadMe в репозитории и косметического рефакторинга), и вероятно ответные действия разработчиков появятся не скоро.

Однако, если мотивации у вас не достаточно - просто перейдите на [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) вместо sshfs - он несравнимо  менее ресурсозатратен, более стабилен и быстр.

Comment: Запилил NFS спасибо